# Python glob.glob to work with optional subdirectories?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, glob

Is there a way to make glob.glob (not glob2) search for files in optional subdirectories in Python 2.7?

I want to search for files ending with "_stats.txt", in these two paths:

> /starting_path/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/Primary_Analysis_Results/results/FASTQ_1mm_currentDate/**Project_1**/trimming_currentDate/cutadapt_S1_stats.txt
>
> /starting_path/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/Primary_Analysis_Results/results/FASTQ_1mm_currentDate/trimming_currentDate/cutadapt_S1_stats.txt

As you can see, the "Project_1" subdirectory doesn't always exist in file paths. For the moment I have tried with the following code:

```
stats_paths=glob.glob("/starting_path/Data/Intensities/BaseCalls/Primary_Analysis_Results/results/FASTQ_*/**/trimming_*/*_stats.txt")
```

but it only works when the "Project_1" subdirectory exists. When it is not in the path I get an empty list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "**" means at least one, so not like that.

Comment: * means 0 or plus, you don't have any suggestions ?